# Should I put honourific on a CV/Resume

Tags: resume, united-kingdom

So I've got a higher degree and some profesional body membership (note, not charted status or similar) that entitle me to use postnominal letters.

Would it be expected to see these accompanying my name at the top of the CV, or does it mark you as rather full of yourself? The roles I would be applying for these qualifications/memberships would be at least somewhat relevant.

Comment: Also see this related thread, summary seems to be it is region specific (where are you applying??) and maybe to list them only if you feel it is relevant to the position http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/423/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-post-nominal-letters-such-as-degrees-in-a-profes

Comment: Applying (mostly) in the UK, as indicated by tag.

Comment: OK I thought I saw UK somewhere but I wasn't sure where, normally I read the question and don't consider tags part of the Q when reading it and don't even notice them really. IMO tags are for categorization and searching

Answer (score 6):

If your professional body membership is relevant to your current job search (i.e. you could imagine recruiters being told "*a good candidate will likely have XXX qualification*"), then I would put it at the top of your CV.

From what I can tell, recruiters pay a lot of attention to certain buzzwords and in-vogue qualifications. Putting something at the top of your CV draws attention and immediately allows them to tick that box.

If your educational level is unusually high (e.g. PhD level), then I would consider including it too. But from a personal perspective, I feel it slips a little towards self-aggrandisement. This may be a cultural thing - I'm British and we are sometimes overly reserved.

Comment: I think in formal settings those with a PHD for CV's or  Papers you have written you do tend to use Dr and it helps to have Dr on your passport for getting upgraded on flights